# Can I do this with one route definition in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, routes, kohana

Here is one of my routes...

```
Route::set('products', 'our-products(/<product>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'products',
    'action'     => FALSE
));
```

By visiting `/our-products`, you can get to the products index (which will call `Controller_Products::action_index()`).

I want the route to work as follows: when adding an optional product, it should call a different method, i.e. if `/our-products/product-a` is requested, instead of calling `Controller_Products::action_index()`, it calls something like `Controller_Products::action_get('product-a')`.

I realise I could do this easily with two routes, but I'd rather to do it with one.

I also though about checking for the param within `action_index()`, and calling another method, but that sounded ugly.

I also tried `__call()` but got this very unusual error...

> Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested in /home/user/public_html/~new/system/classes/date.php on line 3

Is it possible to do what I want? What is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that in one route? Routes were invented for separating different requests to different actions.

Comment: @zerkms They seem related enough to go into one route.

Comment: @alex: don't agree. If you have different `defaults` depending on the url values - they don't seem to be related to one (it is my personal opinion).

Comment: @zerkms What about `<controller>/<action>` ? :P

Comment: @zerkms That is a generic route to handle many actions and controllers. I was hoping I could build a generic route like that (but without resorting to `our-products/get/product-a`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `product` param in `action_get()` method and call `action_index()` (or other) if empty.
2. Read [this topic](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6403) about your unusual error.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the action in the `Controller::before()` method, like so:

```
if ($this->request->param('product'))
{
    $this->request->action = 'get';
}
```